# Can I run cloud init as a different user than root?

Tags: linux, cloud-init

I am trying to run cloud init as a different user than root, because of permissions problem when using git. Is there such a way?

Comment: https://xyproblem.info/ so the real problem is a permissions thing.  You should ask about that problem instead of the problems you have with your chosen solution

Comment: Practically, no. cloud-init expects root privileges for many of the things it tries to do.

Answer (score 5):

> permissions problem when using git

If trying to run a git command in the [`runcmd` module](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/modules.html#runcmd) you could use `su` to select which user to run the command as.

Consider:

```bash
root# su <target user> -c "whoami"
<target user>
```

I haven't tested it, but something like this in your cloud-config might work:

```yaml
runcmd:
 - [su, myuser, -c, "git clone <repo> <directory>"]
```

Answer (score 1):

To execute a command with non-root user with cloud init, you can do this:

```yaml
runcmd:
  - su -c 'whoami' - myuser
```